# Show that a polynomial has 1 real root

Tags: polynomials

Given that $f(x)=2x^3-x^2-11x-12$, show that $f(x)=0$ has exactly 1 real root.

I'm not sure what to do

Comment: This is a cubic.  Have you tried factoring?  Maybe the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?  If all else fails, there's always [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) (seriously last resort).  You do know from graphical considerations that every odd degree polynomial must have at least one real root, right?

Comment: [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Comment: Given this is a cubic, it might be enough to finding the two values $x_1,x_2$ where $f'(x)=0$ and then showing $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ have the same sign (or that there are no real solutions to $f'(x)=0$).  That reduces the problem to a quadratic

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = 2x^3-x^2-11x-12$, By simple substitution it can be found that $x = 3$ is a root of $f(x)$. Thus $x - 3$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Other roots can be found by solving $\frac{2x^3-x^2-11x-12}{x - 3} = 2x^2 + 5x +4$

In $2x^2 + 5x +4 = 0$, $\color{blue}{b^2 -4ac = 25 - 2*4*4  = -7\lt 0}$, So no real roots exist for $2x^2 + 5x +4 = 0$

$f(x)=(x−3)(2x^2+5x+4)$

Thus, $f(x)$ has only $1$ real root i.e., $x = 3$

Comment: At first one could also narrow the search for a rational root using the Rational Root Theorem.

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the form $f(x) = (x-a)(2 \, x^2 + b x + c)$ then
\begin{align}
2 x^{3} - x^2 - 11x - 12 &= 2x^3 + (b-2a) x^2 + (c - 2b) x - ac
\end{align}
which yields $b-2a = -1$, $c-2b = -11$, $ac=12$, or $a = 3$, $b=5$ and $c = 4$. The polynomial $f(x)$ is then
$$f(x) = (x-3)(2x^2 + 5 x + 4).$$
The quadratic $2x^2 + 5x + 4$ can be factored into the form
$$2x^2 + 5x + 4 = \left(x + \frac{5 + i \, \sqrt{7}}{4}\right)\left(x + \frac{5 - i \sqrt{7}}{4}\right)$$
bringing $f(x)$ into the factored form
$$f(x) = (x-3)\left(x + \frac{5 + i \, \sqrt{7}}{4}\right)\left(x + \frac{5 - i \sqrt{7}}{4}\right)$$
The shows that there will only be one real root.

Comment: @A---B $f(x)$ has a leading factor of $2$. With this there is the choice of $f(x) = (2x -a)(x^2 + bx + c)$ or $f(x) = (x-a)(2x^2 + bx + c)$. Both forms are acceptable in terms of comparing the coefficients to find values for $a, b, c$.